# How to interleave two string vectors with equal signs?

Tags: r, vector, coefplot

I am trying to interleave two string vectors into a vector of, I believe, quosures with equal signs.
Here is an example:

```
a <- c('coef_name1', 'coef_name2')
b <- c('clean_name1', 'clean_name2')
desired_output <- c('coef_name1'='clean_name1', 'coef_name2'='clean_name2')
```

As a first step I have tried interleaving, i.e.

```
c(rbind(a, b))
```

but I'm kind of stuck beyond that.
I also tried creating a short quosure by hand, but

```
quo(a[1] = b[1])
```

does not work (it does work with '+' though)..

I need this, because I want to change the displayed coefficient names in coefplot::coefplot with the argument newNames. See page 9 of its documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coefplot/coefplot.pdf

Then I can do

```
coefplot::coefplot(model, newNames = desired_output, intercept = FALSE)
```

Comment: @Gregor, could you elaborate how I input that into the newNames argument of coefplot?

Comment: You can also do `setNames(b,a)` to get your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [coefplot documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/coefplot/versions/1.2.6/topics/coefplot.default) describes `newNames` as a *"Named character vector of new names for coefficients"*

```
# b is a character vector without names
b <- c('clean_name1', 'clean_name2')

# give it names
a <- c('coef_name1', 'coef_name2')
names(b) <- a
# now b is a named character vector

# so this should work
coefplot::coefplot(model, newNames = b, intercept = FALSE)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks so much for explaining that! I misunderstood the documentation.